# algebra precalculus - `value divisible by a prime number`

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have encountered the following question in my textbook:

Let $P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. If $P(1) = 1, P(2)=8, P(3)=27, P(4)=64$, then the value of $P(5)$ divisible by a prime number is ____

I have solved the problem and obtained $P(5)=149$. However, the answer as mentioned in the textbook is $3$. I believe that this has something to do with the final statement: `divisible by a prime number`.

According to my understanding, every integer is divisible by 1 and one or more prime numbers. A prime number is divisible only by itself and 1. What does `divisible by a prime number` mean in this context, and how does it convert 149 to 3?

Comment: I also get $P(5)=149$ which is certainly not divisible by $3$.   Specifically, I  get that  the polynomial is $p(x)=x^4 - 9 x^3 + 35 x^2 - 50 x + 24$.

Comment: 149 is a prime number. Sum of digits in it is 14, which is not divisible by 3

Comment: Right.  Left out the "not".  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: to answer your question:  I have no idea what "divisible by a prime number" means in this context.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot for helping out though :)

Comment: To be clear:  the polynomial is uniquely determined from the assumptions.  We have $5$ values ( counting $(0,d)$) and setting the lead coefficient to $1$ determines $d$.

Comment: WolfromAlpha tells me that $3\nmid149$. I believe your textbook is wrong about it, because maybe for 2 reasons: 1. someone considered $1$ is a prime which is not correct or 2. a mental error occurred when one's setting the question.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Comment: @poyea you're right. I saw the text solution at the back and while solving, the author obtained the answer as 129, which is $ 3\into43 $. The right answer is 149. So I guess he took the smallest prime factor and assumed it as the answer.

Comment: @Allawonder the textbook is Mathematics for JEE Advanced by Cengage learning